# How to enforce float in decimal format when encoding to JSON in Go

Tags: json, go

I have a big.float which I'm encoding into JSON . However the JSON always end up showing the float in scientific notation rater than decimal notation. I can fix this by changing the JSON to be a string rather than a number and using float.Text('f'), however I would really prefer to keep the type as a number.

I was a taking a look at [float.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Format) but I don't believe this is suitable.

A really condensed gist of what I'm doing is below. I do a lot more modification of the value of `supply` before encoding it to json.

```
type TokenSupply struct {
   TotalSupply  *big.Float  `json:"totalSupply, omitempty"`
}
supply := Float.NewFloat(1000000)
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(TokenSupply{supply})
```

This returns:

```
{"totalSupply":"1e+06"}
```

Comment: Show the exact generated JSON.

Comment: {"totalSupply":"1e+06"}

I'd like for this to be printed as 1000000

Note that in this case the number is an integer but it could be a float with a large number of decimals.

Comment: So it's a string not a number :-S

Comment: I've updated the original post to show what I'm doing. The type of value should be a float yet gets printed as a string in scientification notation through `Encode`. If I change the value in the struct to be a string, and then write the value using `json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(TokenSupply{supply.Text('f', 0)})` it gives me the number in decimal form but alas still a string =/

Comment: Do you really need a big.Float instead of a float64? What kind of numbers are you working with here?

Comment: Numbers can be up to 10^30. This is because the datasource doesn't support floating point numbers, so the solution is to have 0 to 10^18 reserved for decimals.

Comment: Note that `totalSupply, omitempty` doesn't work - you cannot have a space after the comma, or attributes after the space will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

big.Float is marshaled to string when converted to a JSON type

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

> Marshal traverses the value v recursively. If an encountered value implements the Marshaler interface and is not a nil pointer, Marshal calls its MarshalJSON method to produce JSON. If no MarshalJSON method is present but the value implements **encoding.TextMarshaler** instead, Marshal calls its MarshalText method and encodes the result as a JSON string. The nil pointer exception is not strictly necessary but mimics a similar, necessary exception in the behavior of UnmarshalJSON.

https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.MarshalText

```
func (x *Float) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error)
```

What can you do about it?

since your float may be more than 64 bits it won't play well with other languages that have to read the JSON value as a number. I'd suggest you keep the number as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Caveats about encoding numbers that don't fit into 64 bits aside, here is how you could marshal a `big.Float` as a JSON number by wrapping it in a custom type that implements [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler). The key is that you can implement the`MarshalJSON` method anyway you like, as long as it emits valid JSON:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "math/big"
)

type BigFloatNumberJSON struct{ *big.Float }

func (bfn BigFloatNumberJSON) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  // Use big.Float.String() or any other string converter
  // that emits a valid JSON number here...
  return []byte(bfn.String()), nil
}

func main() {
  totalSupply := new(big.Float).SetFloat64(1000000)
  obj := map[string]interface{}{
    "totalSupply": BigFloatNumberJSON{totalSupply},
  }
  bytes, err := json.Marshal(&obj)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(string(bytes))
  // => {"totalSupply":1000000}
}
```